# Do you lose your Aufenthaltstitel if you do Abmeldung as a student?

Tags: germany

I am going to Germany as a student. It may be that after preparatory course (Studienkolleg) ends, I return to my home country for a few months while I apply for university. My question is, if I deregister my address and leave Germany for a few months, would I lose my Aufenthaltstitel?

I found some related posts [1](https://old.reddit.com/r/germany/comments/m14kvt/what_happens_after_the_abmeldung/gqboqey/?context=3) , [2](https://allaboutberlin.com/guides/abmeldung-deregister-in-berlin#fn:17) but they are mostly discussing about people who are coming here to ask.

Comment: Strictly speaking one can own more than one apartment at a time in Germany @quantum

Comment: Then one becomes a Haupt and other Neben, you still anmelden and never have to abmelden unless you move out of the country.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: [**IANAL**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL)!

Having said that, the *Aufenthaltstitel* and municipal *Anmeldung* should be two mostly unrelated things. You can read the entire text of the AufenthG law here: https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthg_2004/BJNR195010004.html. It does not mention *Anmeldung/Abmeldung* once (except in the context of registering for an integration course, but that's something else).

The [reasons you may lose your Aufenthaltstitel](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthg_2004/BJNR195010004.html#BJNR195010004BJNG001301310) are:

> 1. Ablauf seiner Geltungsdauer,
> 2. Eintritt einer auflösenden Bedingung,
> 3. Rücknahme des Aufenthaltstitels,
> 4. Widerruf des Aufenthaltstitels,
> 5. Ausweisung des Ausländers
> 6. wenn der Ausländer aus einem seiner Natur nach nicht vorübergehenden Grunde ausreist,
> 7. wenn der Ausländer ausgereist und nicht innerhalb von sechs Monaten oder einer von der Ausländerbehörde bestimmten längeren Frist wieder eingereist ist,
> 8. wenn ein Ausländer nach Erteilung eines Aufenthaltstitels gemäß der §§ 22, 23 oder § 25 Abs. 3 bis 5 einen Asylantrag stellt;

Which in summary mostly means:

- the Aufenthaltstitel expires
- a cancelling condition is triggered
- it's revoked
- because of expulsion
- you're leaving the country for too long
- you're applying for asylum

The "cancelling conditions" here are the most vague. There are a number of following paragraphs about things you may and *may not* do using your Aufenthaltstitel, and these concern things like the maximum number of hours you're allowed to work as a student etc., which would probably be one of the cancelling conditions if violated.

The *Anmeldung* OTOH is regulated by the [*Bundesmeldegesetz*](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bmg/index.html) (BMG), which is not concerned with your Aufenthaltstitel, except insofar as they'll ask for it when you register.

The AufenthG does not stipulate that your Aufenthaltstitel is linked to your *Anmeldung*, and an *Abmeldung* does not automatically trigger the revocation of your *Aufenthaltstitel*. You can probably get into hot water if you don't register your place of residence according to the BMG, as is required of anyone residing in Germany. But if you *deregister* and *re-register* within the parameters of the BMG, you're not violating either law and are not annulling your Aufenthaltstitel, as far as I'm able to tell.

Points 6 and 7 above might be the most pertinent in your case; leaving the country for an extended period of time. Up to 6 months should be fine. You can talk to the Ausländerbehörde to get a confirmation in writing, that the reason and duration for your absence will not result in a revocation of your Aufenthaltstitel.

Comment: Here's the opinion of an (internet) lawyer, confirming the same thing: https://www.frag-einen-anwalt.de/Aufenthaltstitel-nach-Abmeldung--f336776.html

Comment: And another one: [https://www.123recht.de/ratgeber/auslaenderrecht/Erloeschen-des-Aufenthaltsrechts-wegen-Auslandsaufenthalt-\_\_a130299.html](https://www.123recht.de/ratgeber/auslaenderrecht/Erloeschen-des-Aufenthaltsrechts-wegen-Auslandsaufenthalt-__a130299.html) — This one puts more emphasis on the *appearance of emigrating permanently*, which an Abmeldung _may_ contribute to. This should be easily preventable by talking to the Ausländerbehörde and getting something from them in writing.